# Use of different font by name in chapter, section, subsection In memoir class

Tags: fonts, xetex, memoir, chapters

I'm using memoir class and I have an open type font I would like to use through my document.
I have achieved that but I would like to customize it a little in chapter headings, section headings etc.

Let's say, my font is Minion Pro and i use this preamble

```
\documentclass[9pt,draft,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=monotonic]{greek}

\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek, Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=Lining, BoldFont = MinionPro Bold.otf, ItalicFont = MinionPro Italic.otf]{Maria.otf}

\begin{document}
\input{ch01}
\input{ch02}
\input{ch03}
\input{ch04}
\end{document}
```

but i also have and want to use MinionPro Medium, MinionPro Semibold , MinionPro Bold Italic etc.

In detail

Chapter 1 (MinionPro Medium in 14pt)
Chapter Title (MinionPro Medium in 22pt)
Section (MinionPro Bold in 10pt)
Subsection (MinionPro Bold in 10pt)
Body text (MinionPro in 9 pt)
I think i have only fixed the last one..

I am looking at memoir manual, chapter 6, but i haven't found any macros to set the fonts i want by their name, as i did for the whole document in the beginning

Comment: I do not use xelatex myself, but I'd guess that you need to define macros for each of the fonts you need and then specify those using the standard interface to set the sectioning fonts

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That is a lot more useful than a mere code fragment. Also, it would help to pick a font you know everyone will have. Otherwise, it is hard to reproduce.

Comment: Normally, you select font sizes using e.g. `\large`, `\Huge` etc. This is more flexible than using font sizes. (Changing the global font size will change everything consistently.)

Comment: I am also looking for an answer for defining font size for headings.